# How do I clone a custom Intel Edison?

Tags: yocto, intel-edison

I have built a custom Intel Edison that has lots of modifications. I am trying to figure out how to copy the Edison and install it on many other Edison modules. I tried this "backup and restore" tutorial http://www.instructables.com/id/BackupRestore-Intel-Edison/ and it did copy the files but they did not run properly.

I've searched extensively but cannot find the answer. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using linux, i recommend you to modify the yocto image by `chroot`-ing the image.

1. create a mountpoint directory
2. mount the edison-xxx.ext4 to that directory
3. next, chroot to that directory

thats, good luck.